# How can i take a python command as input from a user and give its function as output

Tags: python, documentation

I wanted to let the user enter a python command,
and then wanted to display the function of the command, so i used:

```
x = input("Enter the python command: ")
print(x.__doc__)
```

But every time i run it i get only one output and that is it gives string function.
Can anybody suggest a better alternative so that the output is not based on string?

when i fill myself the output is just what i wanted,

```
print(abs.__doc__)
```

the above given code gives the function of abs, what i wanted but if i entered abs() that got stored in x, then it's not able to give desired output,as it is taken as some string.
I need to know how can i use a user entered command and give it's syntax and description in output.

Comment: What do you mean by "the function of the command"?  Your attempt suggests that you're trying to dump the `docstring`.  If so, you have to access the function object, not merely the function's name as a string.  You need to look up how to access functions within your current name space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

input() will return a string so no matter what the user enters it will always show you the `string` documentation.
you can use `x=eval(input())` but use it with caution